# SonarQube fails the Jenkins job even if job is marked as success

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

We are using Jenkins to build our projects and SonarQube to analyze our code. If the build succeeds and sonar fails, it is marked as failure. We want to mark it as unstable. How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to mark the build state as unstable by searching key words in the build logs.

**Text-finder Plugin**

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. I'll let you know.